# What are all the interaction mechanics for text input boxes?

Tags: forms, hci, textbox

Modern operating systems appear to have fairly standard and consistent behaviour for interacting with text input boxes in various ways. For example:

- Pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> will move the cursor to the zeroth character position.
- Single-clicking will set the cursor under the mouse position, double-clicking will highlight the whole word and triple-clicking will select all the text.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> will additively select one character to the left of the cursor, while adding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to the combination will increase the additive scope to selecting one word per <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> press.

**Where can I find an exhaustive list of all these behaviours?**

Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ControlsText.html) favour technical implementation details over behavioural explanation, and [Microsoft's equivalent document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742442(v=vs.85).aspx) focuses more on explaining which specific text box formats to use in given situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single list since not all keyboards are identical in design.  But you'll get quite a lot of them from

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

and

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

---

EDIT:

I don't know of any generic fine-grain operations for pointing devices (mouse, trackball, touchpad/"skating rink").  They seem to be app-specific, device-specific, or both.  E.g.:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/computer-mouse-tricks-windows

http://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip32.htm

And many of them (e.g. text selection) are more easily done with the keyboard alone.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the direction of keyboard shortcuts. Can you link me to any other resources that enumerate mouse interactions too?